# Entity Framework not able to count the records for nullable types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

Hi I have a class which returns the System.Linq.Expression for my filter values.

```
 var deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<T>(SearchFilter).Compile();
 query = query.Where(deleg).AsQueryable();
```

On this query I am applying sorting and paging which results in expression as:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Domain.Database.Edmx.MyViewTable].OrderBy(item => item.START_TIME).Skip(10).Take(10)}
```

Now when I apply `.TOList()` to this query :

```
 var list = query.ToList();
```

It results in error :

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

My Entity Generated  Looks Like this :

```
public partial class MyViewTable
{
    public System.DateTime START_TIME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> END_TIME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> INTERVAL_START { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> INTERVAL_END { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FILE_Num { get; set; }
    public string PROGRAM_Num { get; set; }
    public string FILETYPE { get; set; }
    public string DIRECTION { get; set; }
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: What does your search filter look like?

Comment: Its a `List<SearchFilter> SearchFilter;`

Comment: `public class SearchFilter`
   {
        public string SearchField { get; set; }
        public dynamic SearchText { get; set; }
        public Op Operation { get; set; }
    }

Comment: The serach expression gives the result as ` {System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Domain.Database.Edmx.MyViewTable]}`

Comment: Could you post an filter expression in Where()? (e.g. Where(w => w.END_TIME.HasValue)).